# How can i get app name or package Name of the app I quit

Tags: android

Suppose I quit an app, say Amazon. How can I fire up an intent or view right after it closes? 
I also want the app name or package Name which was closed..

For example, the way truecaller does it. It opens a view right after you call someone..

Comment: I know of no way to do this. TrueCaller is probably listening for a phone state change and performing an action in response to that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do that - it is rather insecure from users perspective.

TrueCaller is listening on PHONE_STATE event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this, You need to get a [list of all installed apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) and [check if each app is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064137/can-an-android-application-know-when-another-android-application-is-running) and then do your logic. And you can't compare your state with a truecaller. Cause truecaller is using  a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events.

And to fully understand the ability to know when an app shuts down check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601440/1482808)